# Program in local works fine but when I run as chrome extensio I get errors

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I make a chrome extension that sends an email when you press a button whish is from an external site. When I run the program in localhost I get no errors. But when I run it as a chrome-extension I get errors like

```
**Uncaught ReferenceError: Email is not defined
    at sendEmail (popup.js:8:10)
    at popup.js:4:33**
```

Here is the file that I run in Localhost and it works fine:
My html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
 scale=1.0">
     <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js" defer></script>  
    <script src="popup.js" defer ></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
     <button id='hello'>press</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My javascript file:

```
    console.log('EXTENSION GO!!!')
    
    var button = document.getElementById('hello');
    button.addEventListener('click',sendEmail())
    
        function sendEmail() {
          
             Email.send({
                Host: "A server",
                Port:587, 
                 Username : "Email",
                Password : "password",
                To : 'Email',
                From : "Email",
                Subject : "Email 2",
                Body : "Hello",
            }).then(
    message => alert(message)
    );
        
        }

and my manifest:

    {
      "manifest_version":3,
      "name":"Edupass",
      "version":"0.01",
      "content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches":["<all_urls>"],
      "js":["popup.js"]
    }
    ],
    
    "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
    }
    }
```

And here is my chrome extension and the external web site:

My html file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js" defer></script>  
    <script src="popup.js" defer ></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

My javascript file:

```
 console.log('EXTENSION GO!!!')
    
    var button = document.getElementById('hello');
    button.addEventListener('click',sendEmail())
    
        function sendEmail() {
          
             Email.send({
                Host: "A server",
        Port:587, 
        Username : "Email",
                Password : "password",
                To : 'Email',
                From : "Email",
                Subject : "Email 2",
                Body : "Hello",
            }).then(
    message => alert(message)
    );
        
        }
```

and my manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version":3,
  "name":"Edupass",
  "version":"0.01",
  "content_scripts":[
{
  "matches":["<all_urls>"],
  "js":["popup.js"]
}
],

"action": {
"default_popup": "index.html"
}
}
```

And the external

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Subject</title>
<script src="scetch.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="hello">Press it</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use an external URL. Download smtp.js, put it in your extension directory, and load it just like you load popup.js. Also remove `content_scripts` from manifest.json because it's only for web pages, you don't need it for the popup. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: When I remove content_script the extension is not working. In order to be more specific, I will show you my code . Sorry for all this but I am new in this field of coding.{
  "manifest_version":3,
  "name":"Edupass",
  "version":"0.01",




"action": {
"default_popup": "index.html"
}
}

Comment: You've posted three html fragments and duplicated the code that sends email so I can't say what happens and where and why. I guess you're not using the architecture correctly. The content scripts run in the web page. The `action` popup is a separate extension page not related to the web page. Depending on what you want to achieve you may need just one of these or none at all. You'll probably need to rework your question to make it answerable.